# Make this simple loop more efficient in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, loops, vectorization

I am trying to clean a large dataset. I have a matrix of prices in date order with the most recent date in the first row and different stocks along the columns. If a price is missing or NA on a given day for a given stock, I use the price from the day before. If the price on the final day is NA, I leave it.

I start by looping over the whole matrix and using an IF statement for each (i,j) pair. This was extremely slow. The next approach is as follows for the matrix of prices b: I use indexing to find indices which are NA, and only deal with these.

```
for(j in 1:ncol(b)) 
{ 

Index<-which( is.na(b[,j]) | b[,j]==0) 
if(length(Index)==0)
{print("0 Missings")
Index<-c(1)#to ensure its not empty}
for(k in length(Index):1 )#backwards to fill from the bottom
{
i=Index[k]
#If the oldest date is missing, then set it to N/A so that N/A is passed forward as opposed to 0.

if( i==nrow(b) & ( b[[i,j]]==0 | is.na(b[[i,j]]) ) ) 
{ 
  b[[i,j]]<-'#N/A' 
} 
else( b[[i,j]]==0 | is.na(b[[i,j]]) ) 
{
  b[[i,j]] <- b[[i+1,j]]#Take the price from the date before      
}

}

}
```

This is a little faster, but not much. It still takes over an hour for a 400x6000 matrix. I was hoping for a fully vectorised approach, where I did something like:

```
b[[Index,j]]<-b[[Index+1,j]]
```

However, I don't think R will use sequentially updated values. By this, I mean it wont progressively update from the bottom so that new values are used. This is important when I have 2 NA entries in a row, since the vectorised approach above will only fill one. But some sort of efficient sequential vectorised code will update the first, and use this to update the second. Any ideas?

Many thanks for your efforts

Comment: Apparently you want to do a "last observation carried forward" operation. This is implemented in the `na.locf` function from package zoo. (Of course, you have to take care that your missing values are actually encoded as `NA` and not some text. Take care of this during data import.)

Comment: Please decide which language you would like to use and remove the other one from the question tags.

Comment: Im in R at the moment, but I was hoping for a vectorised approach as opposed to a package (Black box) and so I thought the approach would be very similar on either language

Comment: A vectorized approach is not "opposed to a package". Those are orthogonal concepts. Packages are a cornerstone of the R language. Most of the code you use is actually from packages that are distributed with base R. If you are opposed to using (well known and maintained) packages, you are not using the full potential of the language.

Comment: And of course, R packages are open source. There is no black box. You can study the source code.

Comment: Yes youre right, Thanks. They seem to use a cumsum on the Indexes in a smart way.

Comment: Why the MATLAB tag ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My R Studio does not allow me to install the packages MOSS and ZOO, so I have to settle for a solution similar to na.locf. The code is here in case anybody wants to use this approach:

```
start.time<-Sys.time()
nrow<-nrow(b)
for(j in 2:ncol(b)) 
{

  ColumnReversed<-rev(b[,j]) #So we fill from the bottom - Oldest date first
  Index<-!is.na(as.numeric(matrix(ColumnReversed,ncol=1))) #1 for valid, 0 for Missing

  ValidVals <- c("NA",ColumnReversed[Index]) #[NA,final known, second final known,...,first known]
  FilledIndex <- cumsum(Index) + 1  #    [0,0,0,0,0...,1,1,1,1,...,2,2,2,2,2,...3,3,3,3,3...,k,k] + 1
  #This line stores the index of ValidValues which contains the prices (and values to be filled)
  b[,j]<-rev( matrix(ValidVals[FilledIndex],ncol=1) )#Store in reversed order 

}
```

Timing improved from 90 minutes to 65 seconds. AMAZING!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an possibility using the `MESS` package and is essentially not different from @Roland's comment above so I'm only including it here so you can see the formatting. The `filldown` function is written in C++ so it's rather fast:

```
x <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, NA, 17, 18, NA, 20), nrow=5)
 x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    6   11   NA
[2,]    2   NA   12   17
[3,]    3   NA   13   18
[4,]    4   NA   14   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   15   20
```

and then use

```
library(MESS)
apply(x, 2, filldown)
```

which produces

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    6   11   NA
[2,]    2    6   12   17
[3,]    3    6   13   18
[4,]    4    6   14   18
[5,]    4    6   15   20
```

Comment: You should disclose that you are the package author.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a completely `R` version then I have a consideration for you:

First define a proper, big, test set:

```
set.seed(42)
nRow <- 1000
nCol <- 500
test <- matrix(rnorm(nRow * nCol), 
               nrow = nRow, 
               ncol = nCol)
test[sample(nRow * nCol, nRow)] <- NA
```

Then write come code that passes down in the way you want using vectorisation (applicable to each column). PLease note that the horrible excel '#N/A' has been converted to a `NaN` which is maintains the storage mode (i.e. `numeric`).

```
innerF <- function(x){

  # Nothing to change
  if(!any(idx <- is.na(x) | x == 0))
    return(x)

  # Alter first value
  if(is.na(x[1]) | x[1] == 0)
    x[1] <- NaN

  # First value altered
  idx[1] <- FALSE

  # Pass down
  x[idx] <- x[which(idx) - 1]

  # Return
  x
}
```

Then define a calling strategy:

```
outerF <- function(x){

  # Run once
  y <- innerF(x)

  # Run till done
  while(any((is.na(y) & !is.nan(y)) | 
            (!is.na(y) & y == 0L))){
    y <- innerF(y)
  }

  # Return
  y
}
```

The test it against the alternative, and weep.... (hint: use MESS and its C++):

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(MESS)

microbenchmark(apply(test, 2, outerF), times = 100)
#Unit: microseconds
#                   expr    min       lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
# apply(test, 2, outerF) 630.07 652.4505 806.4808 670.6965 686.234 3253.27   100

microbenchmark(apply(test, 2, filldown), times = 100)
#Unit: microseconds
#                 expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
# apply(test, 2, filldown) 107.482 110.048 134.9092 112.329 114.895 1980.016   100
```